# Compare input date value with model property value mvc

Tags: javascript, c#, model-view-controller, razor-pages

in my MVC View I would like to do something like limiting model objects only to objects which property "Date" is greater than date from input calendar. 
In scripts sections in function `drawChart()` I have added
`var start = new Date(document.getElementById("start").value);` but when I try to get this this value I get an error "The name 'start' does not exists in the current context". This is what I want to do:

```
            var start = new Date(document.getElementById("start").value);
            var test = @Model.Where(s => s.Date > start)
            var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
                ['Date', 'Entries'],
                @foreach (var obj in test)
        {
                <text>  [new Date(@obj.Date.Year, @obj.Date.Month - 1, @obj.Date.Day), @obj.Count], </text>
        } ]);
```

How should I do it?

Comment: I have also tried to write: ```@Model = @Model.Where(s => s.Date > start);``` but result was the same

Comment: I think you're getting confused about what happens on the server vs. what happens on the client. The code `var start = new Date(document.getElementById("start").value)` is executed on the client, while `@Model.Where(s => s.Date > start)` is run on the server. The `start` variable is *not* shared between the two. You need to have the client-side code send the start date to the server using something like an HTTP query string parameter.

Answer (score 1):

try viewbag instead, i tried something like that in my code, and it worked fine.

```
 @ViewBag.abc = 'DAN';
            var s = @ViewBag.abc;
            alert(s);
            var test = Model.Where(s => s.BatchName == @ViewBag.abc )
```

in your code try doing it like this:

```
@ViewBag.abc = new Date(document.getElementById("start").value);
    var s = @ViewBag.abc;// this part and alert is just to check the value inside viewbag. 
    alert(s);// comment both these lines .
    var test = Model.Where(s => s.Date > @ViewBag.abc )
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this it worked for me. Thanks

```
@ViewBag.abc = new Date(document.getElementById("s_date").value);
    var axen = Model.Where(s => s.S_Date > @ViewBag.abc )
```

Answer (score 0):

As Jack explained you are trying to access a javascript variable (which is client side) within vs code (which is server side). Every expression that is adjacent to a **@** sign  compiles at server side. You may send that date variable from client to server by putting it in a html form element, then submit it to the pagemodel.